# Logout endpoint allows redirection to an arbitrary url in Keycloak

Tags: keycloak

Since there is no clientId in the logout request, it's not possible to validate the URL against the client's list of Valid Redirect URIs, thus allowing redirection to an arbitrary URL:
https://idserver/auth/realms/realm/protocol/openid-connect/logout?redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fattackers.website

Is there a workaround for this issue or does it have to be a code fix? Thank you.

Answer (score 15):

You can (and should) register "Valid Redirect URIs" for each client in the realm. If you don't and specify i.e. "*" to allow any URL, exactly the thing you describe will happen.

Try it the logout with the realm "master" (with the initial configuration): You'll get the error message "Invalid redirect uri".

Comment: Glad it worked. Please feel free to accept the answer :-)

Comment: This is a serious misconfiguration. I find it interesting that the documentation isn't all that clear about the default behaviour. When the client is created no redirect URI is set, also if done through realm import the value can be omitted altogether without error/warning on import. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: +1 this worked for us (we were getting error for invalid redirecturi). We have /logout with redirect_uri set to /auth to allow new user login